# One role per user CanCan, undefined method 'role' problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authorization, roles, cancan

Really confused. Roles are set up and working nicely following the [one role per user method](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Role-Based-Authorization). My user model is below.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

    ROLES = %w[admin landlord]

    def role?(role)
     roles.include? role.to_s
    end
 end
```

It is when I add the permissions to my ability model I get the following error.

```
undefined method `role' for #<ActionDispatch::Session::AbstractStore::SessionHash:0x10433a5e0>
```

My Ability model is below.

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    if user.role == "admin"
      can :manage, :all
    else
     can :read, :all
    end
  end
end
```

And here is what I see in terminal.

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `role' for #<ActionDispatch::Session::AbstractStore::SessionHash:0x1044d46a8>):
  app/models/ability.rb:5:in `initialize'
  app/controllers/application_controller.rb:6:in `new'
  app/controllers/application_controller.rb:6:in `current_ability'
```

As you can tell I am just learning! Even a nudge in the right direction would be amazing. Thanks.

Comment: I'm guessing there is a problem with the value of current_user. Are you using devise? What did you define in current_ability?

Comment: I'm not using Devise, just coded the login from a Rails 3 book I have.

    def current_ability
     @current_ability ||= Ability.new(session)
    end

Answer (score 1):

the problem is that you defined `role?` method but in `ability.rb` you call the `role` method which is of course undefined

the proper way to do that will be

```
def initialize(user)
  if user.role? "admin"
    can :manage, :all
  else
    can :read, :all
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You are passing a session to CanCan. You need to pass the user that is currently signed in. Im guessing in the explanation of your rails book, there should be a way to access that user from the variable session. Pass that user as an argument to the ability.

If a user is not signed in, I would send a new User.

You would need to refactored the code, to something like:

```
def current_ability
  if session[:user_id]  # Replace with the method to get the user from your session
    user = User.find(session[:user_id])
  else
    user = User.new
  end

  @current_ability ||= Ability.new(user)
end
```

Comment: I see, thanks for spotting. Well I edited my code to say.

   def current_ability
     @current_ability ||= Ability.new(session[:user_id])
   end

But the error I get now is:

    undefined method `role?' for 3:Fixnum

Comment: You are passing the id of the user, but not the user itself. You need to find the User, if session[:user_id], exists.(Like in the code, I posted)